# called object type 'int' is not a fucntion or function pointer in xcode

Tags: c, xcode

i have created macro as following

```
#define log printf("(%s):(%d)  ",__FUNCTION__, __LINE__);printf
```

And i am using it in main function for logging

```
log("Hello world\n");
```

it is resulting in run time error as "**lldb**".
Error in IDE is displaying "called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer in x code"

Comment: note : `log`(<math.h>) has already been used as the name of the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "if I give arguments it fails" maybe you wanted something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG( FormatString, ... ) printf( "(%s:%d)" FormatString "\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__ )

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = 16;

    LOG( "i = %d", i );

    LOG( "Hello World", NULL );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ron, This is what i was expecting.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
#define LOG( s ) printf( "(%s):(%d)%s\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, s );
```

Comment: It is working if i give just string in printf but if i give arguments it fails with the error "May be we are missing the arguments  Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation"

Comment: @anilkumar not sure what you mean. The above macron definition should work as-is, and should be used like this: LOG( "Hello World" ) the \n will be added by the macro.

Comment: #include<iostream>
#define LOG( s ) printf( "(%s):(%d)%s\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, s );

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    LOG("Hello world: %d",x);
}                                                                                                                            Results: (main):(7)Hello world: %d                                                                                    But I am expecting: (main:8)Hellow World: 10 (The first solution gives the expeceted results)